# Android. set different fonts to each item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, fonts

I have a ListView.I want to to set different font to each item of ListView .Who can help me with an examplr?
I want something like this http://www.ulduzsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/font-preference-android-emulator-150x150.png

Comment: do you want to use custom fonts or system fonts?

Comment: I am using custom fonts from assets folder of my  program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this inside list adapter's getView

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
    Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<JSONObject> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        this.mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final Typeface type1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myFancyFont.ttf");
        final Typeface type2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DroidSans.ttf");

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_feed, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label_title);


        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

       if(position == 0) {
           holder.textview.setTypeface(type1);
       } else {
           holder.textview.setTypeface(type2);
       }
       holder.textview.setText("item with pos." + position)
       return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView textivew;
    }
}
```

Also you can define typefaces somewhere else as static final.

Comment: I updated the answer, it's a getView of adapter. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: where did you declared inflater

Comment: I added the rest of adapter.  inflater is declared inside adapter's constructor as usual.

Comment: but I don't have such resource R.id.label_title

Comment: I want something like this http://www.ulduzsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/font-preference-android-emulator-150x150.png

Comment: It's just an example, use the R.id of your actual textview.

Comment: its not textview it is list view

Comment: Are you new to Android?  this is an adapter, inside the getView you "build" and return the list ITEM's view, which in the screenshot you maintained have textview and radio button.

Comment: If you are new to Android take a look to this example's custom adapter part. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example

Comment: worked thanks )))I didnt know that each row can display whole view ))

Comment: please give me your email